# in excel empty cells of non empty rows are neglected using java , POI jars

Tags: java, json, xml, excel, apache-poi

**Excel To Json Conversion using JAVA, POI**

> > Issue: Empty cells in Non Empty rows are neglected.
> >
> > > I am trying to convert an excel file through java to Json.[A2 and B2 cells are empty but these cells are negleted i want even these cells to be counted and return an empty string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFtyE.png)

[output obtained, the 2nd row starts from C2 by neglecting A2 and B2  which has empty values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUs4w.png)

public static String ExcelToJsonConverter(String filePath) throws Exception {

```
try {


    FileInputStream inp = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    JSONArray rows = new JSONArray();

    int coun = 0;


    for (Iterator < Row > rowsIT = sheet.rowIterator(); rowsIT.hasNext();)

    {

        Row row = rowsIT.next();
        JSONObject jRow = new JSONObject();


        JSONArray cells = new JSONArray();
        for (Iterator < Cell > cellsIT = row.cellIterator(); cellsIT.hasNext();) {
            coun++;
            Cell cell = cellsIT.next();


            String val = "";


            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
                System.out.println("Formula is " + cell.getCellFormula());
                switch (cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.println("Last evaluated as: " + cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        val = Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.println("Last evaluated as \"" + cell.getRichStringCellValue() + "\"");
                        val = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        break;
                }
            } else if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {

                val = " ";

            } else {

                val = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);

            }
enter code here
            cells.put(val);
        }
        jRow.put("", cells);
        rows.put(jRow);

    }


    json.put("", rows);


} catch (Exception e) {
    //throw new BsfConstraintViolationException("Please Upload a valid file."+e.getMessage());
    throw new BsfConstraintViolationException("Please Upload a valid file using Download Default BOQ option");
}

String formatJson = json.toString().replace("\"\":", "");

formatJson = formatJson.toString().replace("{", "");
formatJson = formatJson.toString().replace("}", "");
formatJson = formatJson.substring(1, formatJson.length() - 1);


return formatJson;
```

}

Advance Thanks to all

Comment: Busy Developers' Guide of apache poi: [Iterate over cells, with control of missing / blank cells](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterate+over+cells%2C+with+control+of+missing+%2F+blank+cells)

Comment: Thank You very much Axel Ritcher, Its working great :)

Comment: You are welcome. [Busy Developers' Guide](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) bookmarked?